# Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'

Tags: angular

Encountered error regarding to cloning a project from tfs then perform the following:

`npm install`

`npm start`

---

`internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796`

`throw err; ^`

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1
```

Image attached for clear error display:
[error screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HeS8.png)

Comment: Well, if you look at your errors more closely, your `npm install` wasn't even successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove node modules folder. Re-Install the latest npm version. Then run

```
   npm install
```

command.

Answer (score 0):

Remove node modules folder.
Re-Install the latest npm version.
Then run `npm i`.